# encode data input of the raw transaction to update an contract function?

Tags: web3js, javascript, raw-transaction

I need to update a contract by calling one of their function but I cant use web3.js so I need to send a raw transaction.

example of function to be call on the contract:

```
test(address buyer, uint256 amount)
```

my code in javascript:

```
var rawTx = {
   nonce: 'CX350',
   gasPrice: 'C350',
   gasLimit: '0x09184e72a000',
   to: 'myAddress',
   value: 'CX350',
   data:  .....
}
```

How I can encode this call and parameters:

```
test('0xc5622be5861b7200cbace14e28b98c4ab77bd9b4', 10000)
```

??

Comment: Why can't you use web3.js? You will end up rewriting significant chunks of it if you want to send transactions in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the above approach works, but why not use the web3.js library which helps in doing the same. Just download web3.js using NPM (or anywhere else) and get the modules required for the task, by:

```
const_ = require('lodash');
const SolidityFunction = require('web3/lib/web3/function');
```

You can use the web3.js library along with your ABI to find the function definition, using the below code:

```
var ABI = JSON.parse(<your_ABI>);
var functionDef = new SolidityFunction('', _.find(ABI, { name: '<your_function_name>' }), '');
```

After this, you can call the method ***toPayload*** which will help you converting the values that you want to pass to your function into HEX Data.

```
var payloadData = functionDef.toPayload([<value_for_var_1>, <value_for_var_2>, <value_for_var_3>, <value_for_var_4>]).data;
```

**payloadData** can be used as Value for the DATA property. Example:

```
var rawTx = {
 to: <to_address>,
 data: payloadData,
 value: '0x0',
 from: <from_address>,
 nonce: nonce,
 gasLimit: gasLimit,
 gasPrice: gasPrice
}
```

You can use this approach and forget about how many zeros to pad with. As the **toPayload** function handles everything.

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly straightforward as per the [ABI spec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI)

First you need the function selector for `test(address,uint256)` which is the first four bytes of the keccak-256 hash of that string, namely `0xba14d606`.

Then you need the address as a 32-byte word: `0x000000000000000000000000c5622be5861b7200cbace14e28b98c4ab77bd9b4`.

Finally you need 10000 as a 32-byte word: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002710`

So the final data string you require is:

```
0xba14d606000000000000000000000000c5622be5861b7200cbace14e28b98c4ab77bd9b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002710
```

And that's it!

Comment: thanks, it worked :)

But now I face another problem: the raw tx works on the Ether Scan https://ropsten.etherscan.io/pushTx  
however  on web3.js: 
 Error: invalid argument 0: cannot unmarshal non-string as hex data

Comment: You probably just need to put the data in single quotation marks, but it's hard to tell exactly on this info.

Comment: My function 
`test(uint256)`

data:
`'0xb3f4d2350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003039' `

`
    const txParams = {
        nonce: nonce,
        gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
        gasLimit: web3.toHex(47189),
        to: contractAddress,
        value: '0x00',
        data: data,
        chainId: 3
      }
`

still getting the error :/

Comment: I think the function signature of `test(uint256)` is 0x29e99f07, so try that instead of your first four bytes.  I.e. `0x29e99f070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​000000000003039`

Comment: Great! Good to know.